# Does adding "use strict"; to a function block affect methods and properties added later on to the prototype?

Tags: javascript, use-strict

Did a few searches for this and didn't find anything exact.  Please consider the following example:

```
function ConstructIt (param) {
    "use strict";
    // Set up the object
}
```

My question pertains to each of the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** In the same file as above we have the following code:

```
ConstructIt.prototype.methodOne = function (fudgeFactor) {
    // Is this still going to be in strict mode due to having it in the constructor above?
    // Or must I include it here as well?
}
```

**OR --> Scenario 2:** In a separate file, the same code as Scenario 1 (can come before or after the Constructor, obviously:

```
ConstructIt.prototype.methodOne = function (fudgeFactor) {
    // Is this still going to be in strict mode due to having it in the constructor above?
    // Or must I include it here as well?
}
```

In short, what I am trying to understand is how the "use strict"; affects code, and where.  Another good question: Why does JShint recommend only using the "function

Comment: Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to **individual functions** -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode